# How to change axios request config?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

For each request to the backend, I send an access token. If the token has not passed verification, then I save the config of the original request and make a request to update the tokens. If everything is fine, then I re-send the original request. The problem is that the original request is sent with the old token. Tell me how I can update the value in headers.Authorization?

```
import axios from 'axios'

import { setAccessToken } from '../store/authSlice'

export const axiosConfig = (accessToken: any, dispatch: any) => {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api'

    const $api = axios.create({
        withCredentials: false,
        baseURL: API_URL
    })

    $api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
        config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        return config
    })

    $api.interceptors.response.use(
        (config) => {
            return config
        },
        async (error) => {
            const originalRequest = error.config

            if (error.response.status === 403 && error.config && !error.config._isRetry) {
                originalRequest._isRetry = true

                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/auth/refresh-tokens`, {
                        withCredentials: false,
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.refreshToken}`
                        }
                    })

                    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.data.refreshToken)
                    dispatch(setAccessToken(response.data.accessToken)) // new token

                    return $api.request(originalRequest) // <=== original request with old token
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('error')
                }
            }
            throw error
        }
    )
    return $api
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using $api.interceptors.response.use() which is on the response not the request. You will not be able to change the Authorization header on a request that has already been sent.

I would use some type of error handler or axios response intercepter to direct user to the login page if they are expired/not logged in. Then I would have an error handler function that can try to attempt a re-authorization then have the error handler function resend the original request that would then have the updated Authorization token. But remember you still cant change the request that has already been sent.

```
    myAxoisInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      function (config) {
        // This is run on each request so if you have or then update 
 the token for local storage your next request will get that updated token


           const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            if (token) {
              //Assign the token to the config
              //If you need to send a request here to see if token is valid I don't recommend that. If you are using a JWT token you can check if it is expired here and do something else like a redirect to login.
              config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
            } else {
              //Can retrieve and assign token here I typically like to do a redirect here as they are likely not logged or sesson expired. in or something like that. Then allow the sign-in process to add the token to the local storage.
            }
            return config;
          },
          function (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        );
```

Comment: I don't want to change a request that has already been sent. I need to send a new request with the parameters of the old request.

In this case, I get an access token from createAsyncThunk and pass it to $api.interceptors.request. And I don't change it anymore. 

I just needed to add an additional variable so that the token in the header was valid.

let currentAccessToken = accessToken
...
config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${currentAccessToken}`
...
currentAccessToken = response.data.accessToken